# Using in-class defined typedefs/type aliases in base-clause

Tags: c++, inheritance

Often I face a problem of unavoidable duplication of code in class definition, namely I type base-specifiers in base-clause, then I should to type/copy the same code at least one more time for every non-default constructed base: in constructors (in member initializer lists or in its bodies). It is annoying thing to type some of them twice. I see a solution of the problem: is to allow user a using in base-clause of typedefs, type aliases and alias templates defined in a current class scope. I.e. before its definition as it allowed for other symbols defined in current class scope (data members, member functions).

Are there any *C++*-inherent restrictions imposed by *C++* nature to allow forward using of typedefs/type aliases/alias templates, defined in class scope?

For example:

```
template< bool >
struct enable_default_constructor;

template<>
struct enable_default_constructor< true >
{
    enable_default_constructor() = default; 
    enable_default_constructor(void * ) { ; }
};

template<>
struct enable_default_constructor< false >
{
    enable_default_constructor() = delete; 
    enable_default_constructor(void * ) { ; }
};

template< typename ...Ts >
struct X
    : enable_default_constructor< (std::is_default_constructible< Ts >::value && ...) >
{

    // next line containing duplication of code
    using enabler = enable_default_constructor< (std::is_default_constructible< Ts >::value && ...) >;

    X() = default;

    template< typename ...Us >
    X(Us &&... v)
        : enabler({})
        , m(std::forward< Us >(v)...) // using symbol `m` before definition
    { ; }

private :

    std::tuple< Ts... > m;

};

struct S {};
struct N { N() = delete; };

static_assert(std::is_default_constructible< X< int, double, S > >::value);
static_assert(!std::is_default_constructible< X< int, double, N > >::value);
```

I want to use `enabler` symbol in base-clause directly.

Comment: @KerrekSB [Here](https://github.com/eggs-cpp/variant/blob/master/include/eggs/variant/detail/storage.hpp#L339) is good illustration of what I am talking about.

Comment: @KerrekSB In the example code from the question everything is working as it was intended. Absolutely correct. Removing any part (enabler completely or just from member initializer list) leads to wrong code. I sure you heard about EBO and enablers of special functions (say, `boost::noncopyable`), but I suspect you just yet can't understand the code above.

Comment: Ah, I see, the defaulted (and deleted) `X()` is a better match than the constructor template, so the constraints are packaged into the enabler. (Still, inheritance like this seems like a rather complex way of constraining constructors.)

Comment: @KerrekSB What is another way to restrict special functions, different from inheritance? How can I suppress default constructor depending on the template parameters else? Default constructor have no parametres.

Comment: Yes, you're right. While a default constructor may be a template; copy constructors certainly may not, and the detour via inheritance seems to be the only way in either case.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right in thinking you want to avoid writing the name of the base class (for example because it's a long, complicated template), there is a slightly convoluted way of doing it.

applying this to your requirement above:

```
template< bool >
struct enable_default_constructor;

template<>
struct enable_default_constructor< true >
{
    enable_default_constructor() = default;
    enable_default_constructor(void * ) { ; }
};

template<>
struct enable_default_constructor< false >
{
    enable_default_constructor() = delete;
    enable_default_constructor(void * ) { ; }
};

namespace declare_X
{

    template<typename ...Ts> using
    base = ::enable_default_constructor< (std::is_default_constructible< Ts >::value && ...) >;

    template< typename ...Ts >
    struct X
    : base<Ts...>
    {

        X() = default;

        X(Ts &&... v)
        : base<Ts...>({})
        , m(std::forward< Ts >(v)...)
        { ; }

        private :

        std::tuple< Ts... > m;

    };

}
template<typename...Ts> using X = declare_X::X<Ts...>;


struct S {};
struct N { N() = delete; };

static_assert(std::is_default_constructible< X< int, double, S > >::value);
static_assert(!std::is_default_constructible< X< int, double, N > >::value);
```

> but I don't want to repeat the template arguments...

then I'm afraid we have to resort to macros:

```
#if defined(BASE_CLASS)
#undef BASE_CLASS
#endif

#define BASE_CLASS enable_default_constructor< (std::is_default_constructible< Ts >::value && ...) >


template< typename ...Ts >
struct X
: BASE_CLASS
{

    X() = default;

    X(Ts &&... v)
    : BASE_CLASS({})
    , m(std::forward< Ts >(v)...)
    { ; }

    private :

    std::tuple< Ts... > m;

};

#undef BASE_CLASS
```

Comment: The question is about class templates essentialy and template parameter list dependant bases.

Comment: @Orient updated answer to reflect the updated question.

Comment: It is definitely pollution of enclosing namespace, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think so - in a large project namespace "declare_X" would simply be a nested namespace within X's namespace.

Comment: Anyways, I don't want to repeat all the template parameters every time I use out-of-class-scope defined alias template. It is definitely redundant.

Comment: If the solution is to define typedef/type alias to alias template in class scope, then we turn back to the original question.

Comment: Sorry if I am too familiar in discussion. I mean not me (it's just a habit of my language) I mean "one": "Anyways, one don't want to repeat...". Anyways, I can't express my thought clearly.

Comment: @orient answer updated - you're not going to like it ;-)

Comment: Ough)). OK, it can be defeated by co-processor. But why typedefs defined in class scope can't be used prior to its definitions, as the opposite to definitions of data members or member functions?

Answer (score 0):

With a small modification of your class template definition, you could stick the onerous type into the template parameter list:

```
namespace internal
{
    template <typename, typename> struct XImpl;

    template <typename ...Args, typename Enabler>
    struct XImpl<std::tuple<Args...>, Enabler> : Enabler
    {
        using XImpl() = default;
        // ...
    };
}

template <typename ...Args>
using X = internal::XImpl<std::tuple<Args...>,
                          HorrendousEnablerTemplate<Args...>>;
```